# Add multiple prefix and namespace to XML tags using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-2.0, apigee

Sample request

```
<execute>
        <XYZ>123</XYZ>
        <commands>
            <Id>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </Id>
            <Level>33</Level>
        </commands>
        <commands>
            <Point>See</Point>
            <method>No</method>
            <No>2</No>
</execute>
```

Required Output:

```
<ns2:execute xmlns:ns2="http://namespace">
        <ns2:XYZ>123</XYZ>
        <ns2:commands>
            <ID  xmlns="https://differentnamespace">
                <name>ABC</name>
            </ID>
            <ns1:Level xmlns="https://thireddifferentnamepsace">33</Level>
            <ns1:Channel>Sky</ns1:Channel>
        <ns2:/commands>
        <ns2:commands>
            <ns1:Point>See</Point>
            <ns1:method>No</method>
            <ns1:No>2</No>
<ns2:/execute>
```

Can I do this with XSL? I did try but having problem with multiple prefix and in some tags there should be no prefix.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. -- Note that your output does not have a namespace declaration for the `ns1` prefix.

Comment: Yes you can do it with XSLT. You just need a template rule for each element that creates a new element with a different expanded name using `<xsl:element>`. Please show us your attempt so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I some how fixed it. :)